# C:The correct reason for infinte loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I have an argument with another university student about the reason that the following has an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_sign2(void);

int ctr;
char sign1='x';
char sign2='=';


int main() {
    for (ctr=0; ctr<10; ctr++){
        printf("%c",sign1);
        print_sign2();
    }
    return 0;
}

void print_sign2(void) {
    for (ctr=0; ctr<2; ctr++)
        printf("%c",sign2);
}
```

I think that this loop is caused because the `ctr` integer is global and is also used in the function `print_sign2`. Meaning that every time the function `print_sign2` is called the `ctr` is set as 0. Is this right?

Comment: You can answer this question for yourself by placing `printf("%d\n", ctr);` before and after the call to `print_sign2`.  (You're *almost* right.)

Comment: More precisely, `print_sign2` sets `ctr` to `2` every time. See why ?

Comment: Textbook example of why you should avoid using globals where possible.

Comment: Yes thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 6):

When `print_sign2` finishes, `ctr<2` is false. The first time this becomes false is when `ctr` is 2. So `ctr` is 2. Thus the loop in `main` never terminates since `ctr` never gets over 3 and thus `ctr<10` is always true.

Answer (score 2):

`ctr` never become more than 2 in `main`, this is why it's a infinite loop.

Each time `print_sign2()` it set back value of `ctr = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables as loop control variables. That's just poor programming practice. Use local variables instead.

Using local variables for loop control avoids the problems altogether.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_sign2(void);

char sign1='x';
char sign2='=';


int main() {
   int ctr;
   for (ctr=0; ctr<10; ctr++){
      printf("%c",sign1);
      print_sign2();
   }
   return 0;
}

void print_sign2(void) {
   int ctr;
   for (ctr=0; ctr<2; ctr++)
      printf("%c",sign2);
}
```